# Enable Not Null Textbox

Tags: php, arrays, textbox

I have an array of Textbox, by default they are all `disabled`... Some Textbox are empty some are not based on the return values of my query.

```
while ($imps_row1 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt_line_util3,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<tr>";

    echo "<td><input type='text' disabled='disabled' class='txtDis' name='txt1[]' value='".$imps_row1['qualified_borrower']."'></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' disabled='disabled' class='txtDis' name='txt2[]' value='".$imps_row1['allowed_borrower']."'></td>";

    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Is there any way that the moment the page loads, all the textbox that are not empty will not be `disabled`?

Comment: Add condition to check it inside loop.

Comment: in php just don't disable ones with a not empty value.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn This loop may return more than 100 textboxes and I dont even know which or what textbox will have a value or will be empty...

Comment: aren't you echo'ing the value from php? as in `...value='".$imps_row1['qualified_borrower']."'...`? Can't you just check if that var is `!empty()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something this might work using just php:

```
while ($imps_row1 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt_line_util3,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' ".(empty($imps_row1['qualified_borrower'])?"disabled='disabled'":'')." class='txtDis' name='txt1[]' value='".$imps_row1['qualified_borrower']."'></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' ".(empty($imps_row1['allowed_borrower'])?"disabled='disabled'":'')." class='txtDis' name='txt2[]' value='".$imps_row1['allowed_borrower']."'></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Just uses a ternary statement to check if the variable you are echo'ing to the value is empty and if so echo's "disabled...".